# python gzip.open: zlib.error: Error -3 while decompressing data: too many length or distance symbols

Tags: python, gzip, zlib

I want to decompress a huge gz file (wikidata json dump *latest-all.json.gz*
, 104GB compressed) on the fly in python with `gzip.open`.

It works fine for a while. However, after reading 39.7 million lines it yields the error:

```
zlib.error: Error -3 while decompressing data: too many length or distance symbols
```

The function where I do the decompressing and reading looks like this:

```
import gzip
...
def wikidata(filename):
    with gzip.open(filename, mode='rt') as f:
        f.read(2) # skip first two bytes: "{\n"
        for line in f:
            try:
                yield json.loads(line.rstrip(',\n'))
            except json.decoder.JSONDecodeError:
                continue
```

The error in full is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "parse.py", line 95, in <module>
    for line in lines:
  File "parse.py", line 21, in wikidata
    for line in f:
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/gzip.py", line 305, in read1
    return self._buffer.read1(size)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/_compression.py", line 68, in readinto
    data = self.read(len(byte_view))
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/gzip.py", line 487, in read
    uncompress = self._decompressor.decompress(buf, size)
zlib.error: Error -3 while decompressing data: too many length or distance symbols
```

What can be the reason for this? How can I solve the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means that the compressed data is corrupted at that point, or some short distance before it. The only way to solve the problem is to replace the input with a gzip file that is not corrupted.